# How to show only part of the android camera preview?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I need a way to "crop" the camera preview, so that only part of it will show.
For example:
Let's say my camera supports 1920X1080. Now, I have a SurfaceView all over my screen (since my screen is 1920X1080 as well). I want to keep the preview rolling, but "hide" the left side of the screen, so, if I'm looking directly at the camera, then the screen will be split. One half will show the right side of my face, and the other will show nothing.

How do I do that?
Can it be done with Camera api? and with Camera2 api?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can set position for `SurfaceView` like for other `View` i.e. you can set the start of an element beyond the start of screen.

Answer (score 0):

Put the surface view in a relative layout that fill the screen  and  add a new view in the same relative layout with a opaque background up to the surface view. Set this last view to fill parent in height and what you want as width.

This is a code sample where I split the preview into a red view and a transparent view

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#00f" >

    <SurfaceView

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:alpha="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#F00"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@null" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```